# Searching mysql database that has over 3 mil records

Tags: php, mysql

In my project I have to search Mysql database that consists over 3 million records and I will have to find a string with length 15 symbols in my search (Vehicle VIN number) .

My question is:
1. Will that search takes lots of time and system resources ?
2. What kind of field should be the one I am going to search - varchar, text, small_text or ..?
3. Any suggestion to make the search faster will be highly appreciated !

The site is making 1000 visits per day - is this much ?
I haven't tested yet but wanted to share my concerns before doing any coding..

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: `Mysql` is not deprecated. `mysql_` functions that PHP uses are. Are you using `mysql_` if so you should change that but it doesn't relate to your question, or at least currently.

Comment: Create an index on the VIN column and you should be fine.

Comment: MYSQL is deprecated???? u mean `mysql_` please learn about the Database engine and Indexes, if you are trying to search string, then learn full text searching, MAtch against, Sphinx. but here 3 million rows not an issue, i have 10millions records in a project and i am using LIKE with not hurdle.

Comment: 3 million records should not be an issue. 1000 connections a day should not be an issue. Use a varchar for the column and index it. Should function fine after that. If not please add your table schema, and the results of an `explain`.

Comment: Yes, Yes, my fault guys, I was going to add some code, than removed it but forgot to remove mysql notice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience:

We have multiple databases, many of which have far more than 30m rows. With indexing, proper configuration and decent hardware our lookups take ~1ms.  There are multiple factors that affect lookup time.

The most impactful one is indexing. If you add a simple index on the VIN table, you should be able to significantly reduce the amount of time it takes to retrieve data that you need.

Aside from that, I strongly recommend doing MySQL tuning to ensure that your MySQL server has plenty of resources to work with. I recommend using this tool to start out https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl . While it may recommend a lot of things, I strongly suggest researching each suggested change and making sure that it is best for the hardware that you have.

Last but not least, make sure that your machine is meant for databases. (ex: Using Raid5 on database server is terrible). If your machine has an SSD, consider looking up suggestions for MySQL on SSD server configuration.

Comment: Hey Dimi, thank you for your time too. First of all, the customer's website is on shared hosting and not much I can do about the hardware. I will explore the suggested url and see what I can use. Looks like concerns were for nothing :).  Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Mysql still stands strong. Check if you can to update it to a newer version.

Are the VIN numbers unique? How does the [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(SQL_statements)) look?

If the cardinality is good, your data are mostly unique, you can create an [index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) on the column and your search will be (almost) instant.

Furthermore, you want to search only by VIN or by a set of fields, e.g. VIN + other params. If you are searching by multiple fields include those in the index as well.

Comment: Dear Eriks, thank you for your answer ! I will be searching by 2 fields, one is VIN number and second is the service provider. I will put index on both as suggested, thank you !